# How to prune a tree of selective nodes without recursion

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion, tree

I can't solve the following problem without recursion. I get that the solution has to do with making a list of nodes to process but that's where I get stuck.

The problem is to remove all nodes from a tree with a negative value. I wrote an example in Swift below and included the recursive solution I came up with. What is the solution to the problem without using recursion?

```
struct Tree: Codable {
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case children
    case value
  }
  let children: [Tree]
  let value: Int
}

let tree = Tree(children: [
  Tree(children: [
    Tree(children: [], value: 3),
    Tree(children: [], value: -1)
  ], value: 5),
  Tree(children: [
    Tree(children: [], value: 3)
  ], value: -2)
], value: 12)

func prune(tree: Tree) -> Tree? {
  if tree.value < 0 {
    return nil
  }
  return Tree(children: tree.children.compactMap { child in
    prune(tree: child)
  }, value: tree.value)
}

let prunedTree = prune(tree: tree)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let json = try! encoder.encode(prunedTree)
print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)

// {
//   "value" : 12,
//   "children" : [
//     {
//       "value" : 5,
//       "children" : [
//         {
//           "value" : 3,
//           "children" : [
// 
//           ]
//         }
//       ]
//     }
//   ]
// }
```

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to solve the problem without recursion?  AFAICS to do that you would need some form of index to access nodes sequentially, which would either involve creating it in parallel to the tree at build time (and then you're not really using a tree) or creating it on the fly ... and that would need to be by recursion.  Or maybe I'm missing something :-)

Comment: From my understanding of CS, "every recursion can be converted to iteration." What I do not understand is how to practically apply that knowledge. I agree with your observation that a solution requires some form of index. My guess is that a structure like a stack could be used to queue nodes in the tree. Then the question becomes how to translate the pruned stack back into a tree, I suppoose. I'm unsure of this approach altogether.

Comment: You are correct, a recursive solution can always be converted to a looped solution )see https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/latest/Public/recursionConversion/index.html for a deep dive into it) but in this case I wouldn't;t want to unless some performance issue dicatted it.  Recursive might not always be the most efficient, but it's often the easiest to grok.